# colorbox jquery lightbox Scroll with parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox jquery lightbox.

I currently have the main window scroll disabled when the modal is open with

```
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function () {
    $('html').css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
}).bind('cbox_closed', function () {
    $.colorbox.remove();
    $('html').css({ overflow: 'auto' });
});
```

But i think that is not good enough.

I want it so that when the modal is open it transfer the scrolling from the modal to the main window

For example like bootstrap modal 3: http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/183/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the scrolling option set to false?

`If false, Colorbox will hide scrollbars for overflowing content. This could be used on conjunction with the resize method (see below) for a smoother transition if you are appending content to an already open instance of Colorbox.`

From here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

The API also has a resize function. If you have dynamic content, you could resize the window to the size of the content which shouldn't cause any scrolling inside the lightbox.